# How to getback the original elements of jobjectArray?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I have a Java function which will receive variable number of parameters and in JNI I am receiving all the parameters in `jobjectArray`. Now my question is: how to get back the parameters in their original form (they could be strings, double array, int...)?

**Edit:** (based on comments)

Here are the details. This is my function declaration:

```
private native double gsl_stats_all_in_one(String...str);
```

This is my function call:

```
variance = this.gsl_stats_all_in_one((String)message.getBody().get("function2"), 
                                     Ar‌​rays.toString(data), "1","5");
```

Here is the function definition:

```
JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_org_bel_MyJMSListenerAction_gsl_1stats_1all_1in_1one (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr)
```

Now my arr is having all the 4 parameters I which first one is string, second one is double, third and fourth one are integers. How can I get back all of the four parameters in their original form.

Comment: What do you mean, are they not in their original form? Do you mean how to know if the object in the object array are String, double[][] etc? If so, then you can use the instanceof operator.

Comment: Maybe you can show some code of what you have so far and where you are having problems.

Comment: thank you.here are the details:

this is my function declaration:private native double gsl_stats_all_in_one(String...str);

this is my function call:
variance=this.gsl_stats_all_in_one((String)message.getBody().get("function2"),Arrays.toString(data), "1","5");

Comment: and here is the function definition:JNIEXPORT jdouble JNICALL Java_org_bel_MyJMSListenerAction_gsl_1stats_1all_1in_1one
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jobjectArray arr)

now my arr is having all the 4 parameters i which first one is string,second one is double,
third and fourth one are integers.how can i get back all of the four parameters in their original form.

Comment: They are not doubles or integers, you have specifically created strings with textual representations of them, so to "convert" them back you need to parse them from your strings. If you want them as primitive types, why do you first create strings out of them?

Comment: in my function call i have converted all the parameters into strings.actually they all are not strings,only first parameter is a string ,second one is an double array,third and fourth are integers.why i have converted them into strings is my function declaration needs all parameters to be strings.

Comment: can we know the type of the value which is in jobjectArray using instanceof operator in JNI.?

Comment: because my function dclaration will only accept all strings as its parameters.private native double gsl_stats_all_in_one(String...str)

Comment: @johnkrishna Welcome to StackOverflow. Instead of adding code to comments you should click the "edit" link and make any additions directly to your question. This way others can easily see any clarifications that you need to make.

Comment: i have declared my function to take variable number of parameters because i need a generic function which should work for any no.of parameters.

Comment: But you have declared the function to accept an jobjectarray and you always pass it objects that are strings. You say that the 3rd and 4th parameter are integers, but you are passing them as strings. There is no way from the c side to know that your "1" should be an integer. If you want to pass the objects, then you need to pass them as Double, Integer etc, not as String.

Comment: my requirement is my method must accept variable no.of parameters.those parameters could be of any type.is there a mechanism in java so that i can send different types of parameters(without converting them to strings).

Comment: right now i am able to retrieve all the parameters as strings using GetStringUTFChars(running through jobjectArray arr) method.supposing that i know 1 which is my third parameter is an integer,how to getback that ,i mean which method of JNI will do that?

Comment: can i call any java method from native code which will take jobjectArray as a parameter and which will serve our purpose(converting them to original form)?

Answer (score 1):

A jobjectArray does not contain ints or doubles or any primitive types. It contains objects. A jintArray contains ints, etc. You need to rethink your question. If you are trying to declare a native varargs method, the final parameter is indeed a jobjectArray and it contains objects. If your Java code passes ints, doubles, etc., they are converted to Integer, Double, etc., so what you receive in the native method is always an object. You can interrogate the class of each item at runtime via e usual JNI calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a method to take an Object[], which it what you have here, it only will accept objects. To do you a favor, Java will 'autobox' primitive types into their corresponding object types. If you write `whatever(1)` you will get the effect of `Integer.valueOf(1)`.

There is no way in Java to declare a varadic function that takes primitive types. All varadic functions take objects of some sort or another. So you can't get that 'original' primitive `1`, no matter what you do.